# How to get the data for a DataTable from the Controller to View using Ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable

In my main controller, I have a function that gets the data from the database, formats it and output it as JSON. My problem now is how to display this data to the DataTable. Most examples I read have the data saved from a different file from the controller. I would for the data to be from a function in the controller. How do I call that function?

View (SampleView.php)

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>EmpID</th>
      <th>FirstName</th>
      <th>LastName</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>       
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                   "ajax": "main/getDataFunction", 
                   // "ajax": "getDataFunction", 
                   // "ajax": "<?php echo base_url()."main/getDataFunction"; ?>",
                   // "ajax": { url: 'main/getDataFunction', type: 'POST' },
                   "bPaginate":true,
                   "bProcessing": true,
                   "pageLength": 10,
                   "columns": [
                     { mData: 'EmpID' } ,
                     { mData: 'FirstName' },
                     { mData: 'LastName' }
                   ]
                 });        
  });
</script>
```

Controller (Main.php)

```
function getDataFunction() {
  $sampleData = $this->db->getSampleData();

  $data = array();

  foreach($sampleData as $key) {
    array_push($data, array("EmpID" => $key->empID, 
                            "FirstName" => $key->firstName, 
                            "LastName" => $key->lastName));
  }

  $results = array("sEcho" => 1, 
                   "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
                   "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
                   "aaData"=>$data);

  echo json_encode($results);
}
```

Output of echo json_encode($results)

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":1,"iTotalDisplayRecords":1,"aaData":[{"EmpID":"1","FirstName":"JOHN","LastName":"DOE"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about DataTable but what you can do is you can use eval() to evaluate json data first and then fetch your json response values into view.

Old way which I knew is —

$.ajax(function() {
type     : 'get', // or 'post',
data     : {key:value},
dataType : 'json',
success  : function(response){
var html_data = response.eval(); // this will serialize your data object
$('selector').val(html_data.name);
// $('selector').val(html_data.sEcho); as per your output of the code.
// or
$('selector').html(html_data);
}
});

Comment: Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval().
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval